# H tag or image alt text is more SEO friendly?

Tags: html, seo

I have an important title in my website.
Which solution is better than others for SEO?

1. An image with alt text `"my important title"`
2. `"my important title"` text with `h1` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h tag is more important and make sure you ahve only one h1 tag in a page